# Fire and Forget integration question

Tags: integration

Scenario: There is a process initiated when a record is created in Salesforce, and there is an integration with a remote system that does not require Salesforce to wait for a response before continuing.

We have 3 possibilities:

- Using Outbound Message
- Using Platform Events
- Using a Trigger with HTTP callout

Which one is the best recommended solution to accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot use a callout from a trigger directly, and Salesforce's recommended approach is broken. Read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) for some thoughts on how to resolve this (there's a git repo referenced from the end that provides an example that doesn't do callouts but illustrates the idea). Outbound Messages are on the road to deprecation. Platform Events for integration is risky since they do not have guaranteed delivery. I'd go with using HTTP callouts. But this is very much opinion.

Comment: There's probably some information missing that would help with this. Does your organisation have any Middleware currently? Do you know the expected volumes at all? These will help with making the decision. Also have you considered a simple Record Triggered flow/Apex Trigger making the callout?

Comment: consider the dan appleman "Going async" pattern in his latest book [Advanced Apex, 5th edition](https://advancedapex.com/)

Comment: So we have to make an integration with an external system and the most important requirement is that Salesforce does not have to wait for the remote system to get a response back or the so called acknowledgement.

According to this topic from salesforce documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_process_invocation_fire_forget.htm), we found that Trigger with HTTP Callout would be the most suboptimal solution between the 3

Comment: We are not sure which one between Platform Events or Outbound Message to choose since both can do pretty much the job, but the difference is that Salesforce is initiating a retry operation in case of Outbound Message if no positive response is received within the timeout period, according to documentation.

Are we missing anything?

Comment: trigger that does HTTP callout delegates to an async to do this  as per doc: `However, all calls made from within the trigger context must be executed asynchronously.`. If all the requests go into a custom object (Appleman pattern), then you get a free retry on error scaffolding. Outbound messaging are going to be deprecated as Phil W says

Comment: Having not seen the Appleman pattern but assuming you create an object that represents the outgoing message requirement, you can deal with this using a variation (a "command object") of the pattern I cover in my article that does not tag the objects but instead creates the command object and still uses platform events to trigger the processing.

Comment: So you're suggesting to use Platform Events as the most recommended solution, of course, in combination with the command object?

Comment: @PhilW If Platform Events is the best way to go in this scenario, can you describe in couple more words what's about the pattern with the command object?

Comment: It might be a good idea to see if you can access the description @cropredy mentioned in his earlier comment?

Comment: the appleman pattern uses an object called an `Async_Request__c` that has, at a bare minimum, two fields: `Handler__c` and `Params__c`.  This can be thought of as a "Command" object.

Comment: But the main idea is to use a Platform Event to trigger the processing, right? @PhilW

Comment: Yes, though not using the event to store any valuable data. This quickly gets you out of the current transaction and allows the outgoing messages to be processed in a single-threaded manner. You will still have to use some async limits (for now) to actually do the OGM, but you can cleanly do these in bulk (applying callouts per transaction limits) using a queueable and address failures by using a finalizer, tracking try and retry counts on your "command objects". The need for async from the PE trigger may (hopefully) go away in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Phil! Great suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "one best way" to achieve your business requirements, though you should be aware that most options have limitations. Outbound Messages are easy, but may require development time on the far side if it doesn't already have that capability. Platform Events are limited in deliveries per day, so if you expect higher volumes, that could be a problem. Triggers can't directly send callouts, but you can use future methods or queueable classes to send that data.

You've also missed a few options. First, you could use External Services and fire this off from a Flow. This is a technically no-code solution and would be easier to maintain. Second, you could use a CDC trigger to call a Flow or code to send the data. Third, you could use a PushTopic from the other server to subscribe to a channel to get only relevant updates. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a few options, off the top of my head.

Realistically, the reason why we have so many options is because not all external services support all options, so by having as many options as possible, it's easier to make more systems interoperable. The ideal option for your code depends on the capabilities/limitations of the external server, as well as Salesforce limits, so you should select the method that you feel uses the least amount of time to build/maintain that satisfies your business requirements.